Textures tranfer from high poly to low poly
I generated a 3d model in AI. I need to make it in low poly. I found a way to reduce polygons but then textures mess, couldn't make it right with the bake option. How can I edit an unwrapped image? Have suggestions on how to correct the transfer texture from the high poly model to low poly?



For the low poly version you can simply unwrap with the Smart UV Project then bake the Diffuse
